# responsiveslides only shows my first image with https, worked OK with http

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been using responsiveslides for some years, no problem until the site switched to https, now it only shows my first image and does not slide.
are there instructions to change?
Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Comment: And then, start debugging the issue by checking what the browser console and network panel have to say.

Comment: It's possible that somewhere you or your plugin is mixing http/https.  I helped with a question recently where the plugin was hardcoded to `http` - they just needed to get a newer version of the plugin; maybe you need a newer version of your plugin - but you probably just need to update your image urls.  Without details of what "responsiveslides" is or how you're using it, we can't help you.

Comment: Sorry, that I've not been clear - no native English. I ve bee using Responsiveslide http://responsiveslides.com. I changed the image URLs to https, but it didn't help. 
here is the code
https://hotelpetithavre.com/bandeau-test.php

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. There is not enough space to add the codes, therfore I gave the links to the original code that doesn't work in https sites either: http://responsiveslides.com/, and my page  hotelpetithavre.com/bandeau-test.php with the files https://hotelpetithavre.com/js-styles-test/responsiveslides.css, https://hotelpetithavre.com/js-styles-test/responsiveslides.min.js and http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js